# Django templates inheritance between apps

Tags: django, django-templates, django-apps

In Django templates there is `extends` tag used like `{% extends "base.html" %}`.

I want if possible to name templates in several apps the same (like `templates/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html`).

I want the more specialized app (which handles bookkeeping for a particular project) to extend a template in a less specialized app (which handles common tasks for bookkeeping for several our projects) with `extends`. Particularly in the less specialized app I create a template without much design. In the more specialized app I want to present the same information but with a particular design (CSS, etc.)

What can be done about this in Django 1.11?

If it is impossible to use extends of a template with the same template name (but different app), what are other possible ways to solve the problem? I could check existence of `derived.html` and fall back to `base.html` if there is no `derived.html`, but this would lead to writing tedious Python code. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you ever solve this @porton? I have the same goal for Django 3.X.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just name the directories for the templates in each of the apps as following:

```
app1/templates/app1/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html
app2/templates/app2/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html
```

Then in the more specialised app (app2) extend by using:

```
{% extends "app1/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html" %}
```

Or am I missing something here?

#### Edit:

You could link your Python code to point to one template, say `templates/pages/bookeeping_base.html`. In that template you could say:

```
{% if project.is_specialised %}
    {% include 'app2/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'app1/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Then as I described above, the app2 template could still extend the app1 template.

Comment: then I would need different template paths in my Python code: sometimes it is `app1/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html` and sometimes `app2/bookkeeping/bookkeeping.html`